# std::thread crash produces useless callstack in MSVC++ 12.0 but not in MSVC++ 14.1

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, msvc12

The following program is not debuggable in Visual Studio 2013 (MSVC++ 12.0):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <thread>
#include <stdexcept>


int main()
{
    std::thread t([]() {
        throw std::logic_error("WHAAT");
    });
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

When debugging the crash (in debug mode), the callstack is completely useless:

```
>   msvcr120d.dll!_NMSG_WRITE(int rterrnum) Line 226    C
    msvcr120d.dll!abort() Line 62   C
    msvcr120d.dll!terminate() Line 97   C++
    msvcp120d.dll!_Call_func(void * _Data) Line 39  C++
    msvcr120d.dll!_callthreadstartex() Line 376 C
    msvcr120d.dll!_threadstartex(void * ptd) Line 359   C
    kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12() Unknown
    ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart()    Unknown
    ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8() Unknown
```

The parallel callstack window also does not hint on where the program crashed

[image]

What is strange is that if you are compiling the same with **MSVC++ 14.1**, the crash reason is clearly reported:

```
    ucrtbased.dll!issue_debug_notification(const wchar_t * const message) Line 28   C++
    ucrtbased.dll!__acrt_report_runtime_error(const wchar_t * message) Line 154 C++
    ucrtbased.dll!abort() Line 51   C++
    ucrtbased.dll!terminate() Line 59   C++
    vcruntime140d.dll!FindHandler(EHExceptionRecord * pExcept, EHRegistrationNode * pRN, _CONTEXT * pContext, void * pDC, const _s_FuncInfo * pFuncInfo, unsigned char recursive, int CatchDepth, EHRegistrationNode * pMarkerRN) Line 627  C++
    vcruntime140d.dll!__InternalCxxFrameHandler(EHExceptionRecord * pExcept, EHRegistrationNode * pRN, _CONTEXT * pContext, void * pDC, const _s_FuncInfo * pFuncInfo, int CatchDepth, EHRegistrationNode * pMarkerRN, unsigned char recursive) Line 347    C++
    vcruntime140d.dll!__CxxFrameHandler(EHExceptionRecord * pExcept, EHRegistrationNode * pRN, void * pContext, void * pDC) Line 219    C++
    ntdll.dll!ExecuteHandler2@20() Unknown
    ntdll.dll!ExecuteHandler@20()  Unknown
    ntdll.dll!_KiUserExceptionDispatcher@8()   Unknown
    KernelBase.dll!_RaiseException@16()    Unknown
    vcruntime140d.dll!_CxxThrowException(void * pExceptionObject, const _s__ThrowInfo * pThrowInfo) Line 136    C++
>   Sandbox2017.exe!main::__l2::<lambda>() Line 13  C++
    Sandbox2017.exe!std::_Invoker_functor::_Call<void <lambda>(void) >(main::__l2::void <lambda>(void) && _Obj) C++
    Sandbox2017.exe!std::invoke<void <lambda>(void) >(main::__l2::void <lambda>(void) && _Obj)  C++
    Sandbox2017.exe!std::_LaunchPad<std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void <lambda>(void) >,std::default_delete<std::tuple<void <lambda>(void) > > > >::_Execute<0>(std::tuple<void <lambda>(void) > & _Tup, std::integer_sequence<unsigned int,0> __formal) Line 240  C++
    Sandbox2017.exe!std::_LaunchPad<std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void <lambda>(void) >,std::default_delete<std::tuple<void <lambda>(void) > > > >::_Run(std::_LaunchPad<std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void <lambda>(void) >,std::default_delete<std::tuple<void <lambda>(void) > > > > * _Ln) Line 247   C++
    Sandbox2017.exe!std::_LaunchPad<std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void <lambda>(void) >,std::default_delete<std::tuple<void <lambda>(void) > > > >::_Go() Line 232 C++
    Sandbox2017.exe!std::_Pad::_Call_func(void * _Data) Line 210    C++
    ucrtbased.dll!invoke_thread_procedure(unsigned int(__stdcall*)(void *) procedure, void * const context) Line 92 C++
    ucrtbased.dll!thread_start<unsigned int (__stdcall*)(void *)>(void * const parameter) Line 115  C++
    kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12() Unknown
    ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart()    Unknown
    ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8() Unknown
```

[image]

Is there anything I can configure to make the code debuggable in VS2013? Or is it a compiler bug?

Comment: I guess maybe the MSVC12 debugger isn’t as sophisticated as the 14.1, so the output isn’t very helpful.

Comment: Hmya, both the CRT and the std::thread implementation were completely rewritten at VS2015.  No doubt inspired by complaints pretty similar to yours, the VS2013 version uses try/catch(...)-em-all to trap unhandled exceptions in the threaded code.  Stack is unwound so you can't see where it came from.  You diagnose it by stopping the debugger on the first-chance exception: Debug > Exceptions > tick the Thrown checkbox for C++ exceptions.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks, this is an explanation and if I tick stopping on all thrown exception, I come out at the right line. Unfortunately, this (as you indicated with the catch-em-all trap) also stops on properly handled exceptions - after all, this is why it worked. So this is not usable in my current code base :-/ Strange decision to introduce a catch all but at least it has been fixed for newer compiler versions

Comment: Always a good reminder to never use exceptions for flow control.  You can change this setting while you are busy debugging, so you can at least make it to a breakpoint on the thread entry function or last-known-good code.

Comment: :-) might be a lesson here

Comment: Seems like a nice excuse to upgrade to the latest VS2017 ;-)